# C#. Библиотека DocX. Редактирование списков в документе

Tags: c#, docx

Задача: в документе docx имеется список, в него нужно добавить элементы. Использую библиотеку `Xceed.Words.NET (DocX)` для редактирования файлов, так как она самая удобная из бесплатных.

Код вроде этого

```
document = DocX.Load(pathIn);
var list = document.Lists.First();
// list.AddItem(paragraph); ???
document.AddListItem(list, "NEW ITEM");
document.InsertList(list);
```

Не редактирует список, а добавляет его вконец документа, при этом старый список остаётся на месте, но новый продолжает нумерацию старого.

Как использовать метод AddItem не разобрался. В исходниках либы этот метод сначала проверяет, является ли параграф isListItem, то есть любой параграф туда не подсунешь.

Если кто-то работал с этой библиотекой, подскажите возможные варианты решения или хотя бы в какую сторону копать. Официальную документацию уже всю перерыл.

До этого, когда нужно было создавать списки после метки в документе, я использовал следующий способ:

```
private static void LablesToLists()
{
    //Ищем параграфы с меткой
    var paragraphs = document.Paragraphs.Where(p => p.Text.Contains("{{LIST}}")).ToList();

    foreach (var i in paragraphs)
    {
        var list = document.AddList(listType: ListItemType.Numbered);
        document.AddListItem(list, "ITEM 1");
        document.AddListItem(list, "ITEM 2");
        document.AddListItem(list, "ITEM 3");
        document.AddListItem(list, "ITEM 4");
        document.AddListItem(list, "ITEM 5");
        
        //После параграфа вставляем список
        i.InsertListAfterSelf(list);
    }

    // Удаляем параграфы
    paragraphs.ForEach(p => document.RemoveParagraph(p));
}
```

Но в данном случае нужно сохранить исходное форматирование списка. Возможно, можно так же создать новый список, но как-то применить к нему стили прошлого (отступы, маркеры и т.д.).

Comment: Насколько мне известно инструменты для работы со списками и таблицами в платной версии.Я бы лучше использовал OpenXml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы рассматриваете для себя удобную и бесплатную библиотеку для работы с .doc, .docx то указанная вами библиотека условно бесплатная.
Применить все стили к элементу можно только скопировав его, это наиболее простой способ, а [Clone lists or tables](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX#:%7E:text=YES-,Clone%20lists%20or%20tables,-YES) входит в платную версию этой библиотеки.
Поэтому я бы в вашем случае использовал OpenXml,вот пример, где мы копируем элемент первого списка в документе и вставляем его в конец списка, затем изменяем его текст, при этом все стили сохраняются, выглядит это не очень сложно:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathIn = "pathToDoc";
        string newText = "New element";

        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathIn, true))
        {
            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            // Находим последний элемент списка
            Paragraph lastListParagraph = body.Descendants<Paragraph>().LastOrDefault(p => p.ParagraphProperties?.NumberingProperties != null);

            if (lastListParagraph != null)
            {
                // Создаем новый элемент списка, скопировав содержимое из последнего элемента списка
                Paragraph newParagraph = new Paragraph();
                foreach (OpenXmlElement element in lastListParagraph.Elements())
                {
                    newParagraph.Append((OpenXmlElement)element.CloneNode(true));
                }

                // Изменяем текст скопированного элемента
                Run run = newParagraph.Descendants<Run>().FirstOrDefault();
                if (run != null)
                {
                    Text text = run.Descendants<Text>().FirstOrDefault();
                    if (text != null)
                    {
                        text.Text = newText;
                    }
                }

                // Вставляем новый элемент списка
                lastListParagraph.InsertAfterSelf(newParagraph);
            }

            doc.Save();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Элемент добавлен в список!");
    }

}
```